# Can't disable tap highlight color on iPad app

Tags: ipad, safari, mobile-safari

I'm creating a web page that needs to be viewable on an iPad.

Everything's great, but every time I click something, there's this annoying black flash. I've tried quite a few solutions:

```
html {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout:none;
} 


<script type="text/javascript">
    document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout = "none";
</script>
```

Even adding it to the element itself:

```
.viewCont {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 690px;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout:none;
}
```

It works when I view it in Safari on my iPad, but when I make it a standalone dashboard app, the flicker returns.

Anyone have an hints or advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to applied this to all elements and not just to HTML tag. Try like this

```
html * {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout:none;
}
```

Comment: By the way. To get rid of the annoying black highlight, you just have to use "-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);"